# Javascript regexp match of location.hash

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i match every variable that comes after the text "flt_man" and before "," in the following hash string?

```
#flt_man100,flt_man234,flt_man334,flt_manABC,
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
var check = location.hash.match(/flt_man([^,]*)/g);
```

I need the match to return an array with values 100,234,334,"ABC"

Comment: Split on commas first.  Then, match.  Also if your prefix is always 4 characters, use substring instead of match.

Comment: Does'nt work how exactly, seems to do just as expected in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrPXf/) ?

Comment: @adeneo `need the match to return an array with values 100,234,334,"ABC"`

Comment: for idiocy sake you can go so low as to do this: `location.hash.substr(1).replace(/(^flt_man|,$)/g, '').split(',flt_man')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less expensive alternative (not that perf matters much here)

```
var str = "#flt_man100,flt_man234,flt_man334,flt_manABC,";
var arr = str.replace(/[#]?flt_man/g,'').splitCast(',');
arr.pop();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/tfaLp/)

this uses a couple functions i thought were useful enough to abstract

```
String.prototype.splitCast = function(S){
    var arr = this.split(S);
    for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++){
        var value= arr[i];
           arr[i] = !isNaN(parseInt(value,10)) && (parseFloat(value,10) == parseInt(value,10)) ? parseInt(value) : value;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: oh i see you wanted integers not strings. Well...exercise to the reader  then ;)

Comment: use `splitCast()` i added to convert those integers

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var str = "#flt_man100,flt_man234,flt_man334,flt_manABC,";
var regex = /flt_man([^,]*)/g;
var arr = new Array();

var result; 
while(result = regex.exec(str)){
    arr.push(result[1]); //can check if numeric
}
console.log(arr); //arr contains what you need
```

[**Link to fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LrPXf/1/)

To check if numeric you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/759019), and call `parseInt()` right afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
// [100, 234, 334, "ABC"]
console.log(location.hash.substr(1) // Get rid of the '#'
    .split(',')
    .filter(function (param) { // Find the parameters
        return /^flt_man/.test(param);
    })
    .map(function (param) { // Get rid of the prefix
        return param.substr('flt_man'.length);
    })
    .map(function (param) { // Optionally cast them to numbers
        return +param || param;
    }));
```